# What is the full form of bnd.bnd file in Osgi?

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, liferay-7

I'm looking for the full form of **bnd.bnd** file present inside an OSGi module.
I've searched almost everywhere on Google but can't find the exact result.
If anybody knows the full form then please tell me with the reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

bnd.bnd is the configuration file for the tool bnd, often also embedded into maven-bnd-plugin. The tooling creates the OSGi manifest with minimal configuration effort.
You can find documentation at https://bnd.bndtools.org/ .

The documentation there probably does not exhaustively explain all possible settings but I think it is the best source of information.